# Knockout Change Event Firing when updating data set (dependant dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm hoping this is just me being a bit of a prune but I am having trouble with the change event firing when I don't want it to. I will try and keep it short and sharp.

I have two drop downs, Country and City. both of these are bound as follows:

```
<select data-bind="options: Countries, event: { change: IChanged }, value: CountrySelected">
<select data-bind="options: Cities, event: { change: IChanged }, value: CitySelected">
```

My little view model

```
self.Countries = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);
self.CountrySelected = ko.observable();
self.CitySelected = ko.observable();
```

Now my function `IChanged()`

```
self.IChanged = function(item) {
    GoGetMyOptions().done(function(response) {
        self.Cities(response);    
    });
}
```

### The problem!

when calling `self.Cities(response);` it triggers the change event on the City drop down, this means that drop down will call the method again.

### Caveat

I have simplified this, I could have 1 to 80 filters. In my code I basically go off and load the drop down options for everything on the right, problem is it calls the change event for everything on the right :O Ideas anyone?

### A more complicated example (closer to my code

I actually have a filter collection, `self.FilterCollection`, each filter has the following:

```
self.DropDownValues = ko.observableArray([]);
self.SelectedValue = ko.observable();
```

You can see that when a drop down is selected, it updates the selected value and THEN refreshed the `DropDownValues` array for all filters to the right.

In a rather awkward scenario,

1. A user has a CITY selected
2. They select a COUNTRY
3. The CITY list is update
4. Thus resetting the current value**

Number 4 will trigger a subscription I believe...

### A Full Scenario

There are 4 drop downs, A, B, C and D.

When a user selects a value from A, I will iterate through the remaining drop downs and call `getValues`, this will then update the `DropDownValues` observable.

Therefore, I want, **1** UI event to fire saying "the user changed drop down a", I then need to make **3** ajax calls to load B, C and D and update the observable array.

My problem is that when the User selects A, it makes 3 ajax calls correctly but upon setting the value of B it triggers the event...

This then means B will make 2 ajax calls to update C and D. So when a user selects something in drop down A it actually fires:

1 UI event, 3 Ajax calls, 1 UI event, 2 ajax calls, 1 UI event, 1 ajax call and then one final UI event. So to sumarize, one click by the user makes 4 UI event calls and 6 ajax calls :(

Comment: is the `event {...}` without a colon a typo in your question ?

Comment: Yes, I should say, the event works perfectly. It's just unfortunate that when I choose a country, the event fires twice...

Comment: Why don't you just subscribe to `CountrySelected` ?

Comment: I have expanded my Question slightly :)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your issue is that you have an infinite loop when you select a dropdown? What about rate limiting your observables? Or some kind of locking mechanism to specify that your observable just have been triggered and does not need to be triggered again?

Comment: What about deferred updates : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Comment: Deferred might work, I haven't got my head around. It's not a loop no but close, I will expand.

Comment: Does my example make sense?

Comment: Just as a thought, I might be able to set the dropdownvalues as a computed?! not sure what I can target them at though?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a gut feeling you've oversimplified to ask the question, but as it stands there are two main points to make about your repro:

1. You're subscribing to a *DOM* event. No need for that: use a view model based subscription instead. It'll give you a lot more control and allow you to unit test it as well.
2. You're calling `IChanged` on changing the `Cities` dropdown, which makes no sense. Why update the list of available cities when the user changes that city?

Anyways, here's a way to prevent the looping update:

```js
function GoGetMyOptions(country) {
  console.log("Doing ajaxy stuff");
  return {
    done: function(callback) {
      if (country === "USA") callback(["New York", "L.A.", "Chicago"]);
      if (country === "GBR") callback(["London", "Manchester", "Leeds"]);
      if (country === "GER") callback(["Bonn", "Koln", "Hamburg"]);
    }
  };
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.Countries = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.CountrySelected = ko.observable();
  self.CitySelected = ko.observable();
  
  self.CountrySelected.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    GoGetMyOptions(newVal).done(function(response) {
      self.Cities(response);
    });
  });

}

var vm = new ViewModel();

vm.Countries.push("USA", "GBR", "GER");

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: Countries, value: CountrySelected"></select>
<select data-bind="options: Cities, value: CitySelected"></select>
```

As you can see on the console, no Ajax calls would happen when changing the City, only when changing the country.

Comment: I need to sit down and update my question from the start, simplifying never helps haha

However, You have raise some points which will help clean up my code. The reason I added the change to event to cities is because the user can configure multiple filters, I have no way of knowing how many there will be :)

Comment: @Heberda If your actual question deviates quite a lot from this one, you could consider creating a new one, getting some fresh attention for it.

Comment: Maybe I should, I don't like spamming though haha this has given me a lot of thoughts, I have working code but there are a lot of wasted knockout events going off in the background!

Comment: It's a fine line. If you repost very similar / near-duplicate questions you tend to get negative response, but similarly an ever-changing question also [tends to be frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/162730). You should be okay though as you've obviously shown much effort, which is much appreciated. Final decision is up to you :-)